# I was trying to convert a single python .py to windows executable .exe using pyinstaller and it always crashes

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

C:\Users\pheelz\Desktop>pyinstaller -w test.py

here is the error i got

500 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
501 INFO: Python: 3.8.0
502 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.10240-SP0
512 INFO: wrote C:\Users\pheelz\Desktop\test.spec
538 INFO: UPX is not available.
568 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\pheelz\Desktop', 'C:\Users\pheelz\Desktop']
569 INFO: checking Analysis
1167 INFO: checking PYZ
1168 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
1169 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\pheelz\Desktop\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pheelz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe__main__.py", line 7, in 
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "", line 18, in 
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 98, in **init**
    self.**postinit**()
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in **postinit**
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 128, in assemble
    self.code_dict = {
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 129, in 
    key: strip_paths_in_code(code)
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 654, in strip_paths_in_code
    consts = tuple(
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 655, in 
    strip_paths_in_code(const_co, new_filename)
  File "c:\users\pheelz\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 662, in strip_paths_in_code
    return code_func(co.co_argcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize,
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are using PyInstaller 3.4 on Python 3.8.0.

PyInstaller works **ONLY** with Python 2.7 and 3.4—3.7 as stated [here](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)

> Maybe you should downgrade your environment to Python 3.7.5